# what does State means in Google Drive OAuth 2.0 API

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

Hell.

In the documentation of google drive SDK, it is not mentioned what does setState create.

I'm going to implement  Google drive Server-side Authorization. I found the code in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-server).

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2;
import com.google.api.services.oauth2.model.Userinfo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

// ...

class MyClass {

  // Path to client_secrets.json which should contain a JSON document such as:
  //   {
  //     "web": {
  //       "client_id": "[[YOUR_CLIENT_ID]]",
  //       "client_secret": "[[YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET]]",
  //       "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  //       "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  //     }
  //   }
  private static final String CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION = "client_secrets.json";

  private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "<YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI>";
  private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");

  private static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = null;

  /**
   * Exception thrown when an error occurred while retrieving credentials.
   */
  public static class GetCredentialsException extends Exception {

    protected String authorizationUrl;

    /**
     * Construct a GetCredentialsException.
     *
     * @param authorizationUrl The authorization URL to redirect the user to.
     */
    public GetCredentialsException(String authorizationUrl) {
      this.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    }

    /**
     * Set the authorization URL.
     */
    public void setAuthorizationUrl(String authorizationUrl) {
      this.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    }

    /**
     * @return the authorizationUrl
     */
    public String getAuthorizationUrl() {
      return authorizationUrl;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Exception thrown when a code exchange has failed.
   */
  public static class CodeExchangeException extends GetCredentialsException {

    /**
     * Construct a CodeExchangeException.
     *
     * @param authorizationUrl The authorization URL to redirect the user to.
     */
    public CodeExchangeException(String authorizationUrl) {
      super(authorizationUrl);
    }

  }

  /**
   * Exception thrown when no refresh token has been found.
   */
  public static class NoRefreshTokenException extends GetCredentialsException {

    /**
     * Construct a NoRefreshTokenException.
     *
     * @param authorizationUrl The authorization URL to redirect the user to.
     */
    public NoRefreshTokenException(String authorizationUrl) {
      super(authorizationUrl);
    }

  }

  /**
   * Exception thrown when no user ID could be retrieved.
   */
  private static class NoUserIdException extends Exception {
  }

  /**
   * Retrieved stored credentials for the provided user ID.
   *
   * @param userId User's ID.
   * @return Stored Credential if found, {@code null} otherwise.
   */
  static Credential getStoredCredentials(String userId) {
    // TODO: Implement this method to work with your database. Instantiate a new
    // Credential instance with stored accessToken and refreshToken.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

  /**
   * Store OAuth 2.0 credentials in the application's database.
   *
   * @param userId User's ID.
   * @param credentials The OAuth 2.0 credentials to store.
   */
  static void storeCredentials(String userId, Credential credentials) {
    // TODO: Implement this method to work with your database.
    // Store the credentials.getAccessToken() and credentials.getRefreshToken()
    // string values in your database.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

  /**
   * Build an authorization flow and store it as a static class attribute.
   *
   * @return GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow instance.
   * @throws IOException Unable to load client_secrets.json.
   */
  static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow getFlow() throws IOException {
    if (flow == null) {
      HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
      JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
      GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
          GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory,
              MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION));
      flow =
          new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
              .setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force").build();
    }
    return flow;
  }

  /**
   * Exchange an authorization code for OAuth 2.0 credentials.
   *
   * @param authorizationCode Authorization code to exchange for OAuth 2.0
   *        credentials.
   * @return OAuth 2.0 credentials.
   * @throws CodeExchangeException An error occurred.
   */
  static Credential exchangeCode(String authorizationCode)
      throws CodeExchangeException {
    try {
      GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = getFlow();
      GoogleTokenResponse response =
          flow.newTokenRequest(authorizationCode).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
      return flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("An error occurred: " + e);
      throw new CodeExchangeException(null);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Send a request to the UserInfo API to retrieve the user's information.
   *
   * @param credentials OAuth 2.0 credentials to authorize the request.
   * @return User's information.
   * @throws NoUserIdException An error occurred.
   */
  static Userinfo getUserInfo(Credential credentials)
      throws NoUserIdException {
    Oauth2 userInfoService =
        new Oauth2.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credentials).build();
    Userinfo userInfo = null;
    try {
      userInfo = userInfoService.userinfo().get().execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
    if (userInfo != null && userInfo.getId() != null) {
      return userInfo;
    } else {
      throw new NoUserIdException();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve the authorization URL.
   *
   * @param emailAddress User's e-mail address.
   * @param state State for the authorization URL.
   * @return Authorization URL to redirect the user to.
   * @throws IOException Unable to load client_secrets.json.
   */
  public static String getAuthorizationUrl(String emailAddress, String state) throws IOException {
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl urlBuilder =
        getFlow().newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).setState(state);
    urlBuilder.set("user_id", emailAddress);
    return urlBuilder.build();
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve credentials using the provided authorization code.
   *
   * This function exchanges the authorization code for an access token and
   * queries the UserInfo API to retrieve the user's e-mail address. If a
   * refresh token has been retrieved along with an access token, it is stored
   * in the application database using the user's e-mail address as key. If no
   * refresh token has been retrieved, the function checks in the application
   * database for one and returns it if found or throws a NoRefreshTokenException
   * with the authorization URL to redirect the user to.
   *
   * @param authorizationCode Authorization code to use to retrieve an access
   *        token.
   * @param state State to set to the authorization URL in case of error.
   * @return OAuth 2.0 credentials instance containing an access and refresh
   *         token.
   * @throws NoRefreshTokenException No refresh token could be retrieved from
   *         the available sources.
   * @throws IOException Unable to load client_secrets.json.
   */
  public static Credential getCredentials(String authorizationCode, String state)
      throws CodeExchangeException, NoRefreshTokenException, IOException {
    String emailAddress = "";
    try {
      Credential credentials = exchangeCode(authorizationCode);
      Userinfo userInfo = getUserInfo(credentials);
      String userId = userInfo.getId();
      emailAddress = userInfo.getEmail();
      if (credentials.getRefreshToken() != null) {
        storeCredentials(userId, credentials);
        return credentials;
      } else {
        credentials = getStoredCredentials(userId);
        if (credentials != null && credentials.getRefreshToken() != null) {
          return credentials;
        }
      }
    } catch (CodeExchangeException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      // Drive apps should try to retrieve the user and credentials for the current
      // session.
      // If none is available, redirect the user to the authorization URL.
      e.setAuthorizationUrl(getAuthorizationUrl(emailAddress, state));
      throw e;
    } catch (NoUserIdException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // No refresh token has been retrieved.
    String authorizationUrl = getAuthorizationUrl(emailAddress, state);
    throw new NoRefreshTokenException(authorizationUrl);
  }

}
```

First here, I should invoke getCredentials method, which has 2 parameters - Authorization code and State. here,  what should state be? where can I get this? what does this means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows to you pass an arbitrary string to consent page, and when consent page is redirecting back to your application it keeps the state as a query parameter. It's usually used to keep information about the next page and the state of the page.

If you dont have a state to keep for post-redirect, you can pass `null`.